# HTTP POST request using java 16 or above to UNIX domain socket server

Tags: java, rest, http, unix-socket

I have server that can be communicate using REST api over UNIX domain socket.
I want to have java application that can do POST operation on UNIX domain socket using JAVA 16 or above. But, I have no idea how i can create HTTPclient for UNIX domain socket without using third party library?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any idea to send POST request to server where UNIX socket is open?

Comment: for example, I used this part of code to make POST request on UNIX socket.
But it didn't work. 
           
  HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(inputJson))
                    .uri(URI.create(testendpoint))
                    .setHeader("User-Agent", "Bot")
                    .build();

Comment: If you know the answer I would appreciate your help.

Comment: @DuncG I need help to execute POST request on UNIX socket from JAVA application

Comment: Try to get started with a test program to download a page (from any site), then work on your post and after that edit this question with details of what you've tried and all error details (as "it didn't work" isn't helpful).

Comment: @DuncG with REST api over http connection, I have done POST operations and all other operations.  
But with UNIX socket, I have no idea.

Comment: @DuncG Have you worked with unix socket before in JAVA application?

Comment: Sorry but I've focussed on wrong problem. Have a look at the JEP-380 and see if there are helpful pages in say Baelung.com [such as](https://www.baeldung.com/java-unix-domain-socket).